# nginx - serving stale cache response while updating

Tags: nginx, cache

In nginx I am using the

```
proxy_cache_use_stale updating
```

directive (http://nginx.org/en/docs/http/ngx_http_proxy_module.html#proxy_cache_use_stale) so that concurrent request to an invalidated cached content only send 1 request to the upstream (the non-first request respond with stale content while the first request is updating the content).

this works well.

Now is there a way to also have the first request respond immediately with stale content, while at the same time triggering the update ?

right now, the response time is very good for non-first invalidating request, but the first one needs to wait until the backend responds. I would prefer serving stale content until the cache is updated.

Answer (score 13, accepted):

What you're looking for is called stale-while-revalidate (RFC 5861) and it's 
implemented in nginx as a directive called [proxy_cache_background_update](http://nginx.org/en/docs/http/ngx_http_proxy_module.html#proxy_cache_background_update).    Similar functionality can be found [in Varnish 4](https://www.varnish-software.com/blog/grace-varnish-4-stale-while-revalidate-semantics-varnish) and in Squid this is called [Collapsed Forwarding](http://wiki.squid-cache.org/Features/CollapsedForwarding).

Comment: Please update your answer. Since April 2016 it is updated (see Richs answer)

Answer (score 8):

This feature was added in `nginx` 1.11 (April 2016) as [proxy_cache_background_update](http://nginx.org/en/docs/http/ngx_http_proxy_module.html#proxy_cache_background_update)

Comment: The stable release that will include this feature is 1.12.  Hopefully in about a month.

Comment: We currently have 1.12.1. See also: [Stale-while-revalidate cache replacement from Varnish](https://stackoverflow.com/a/40134179/562769)

Answer (score 5):

If you want to guarantee that only one request can hit the proxied server at a time (e.g. server is fragile to high load induced by the request), you need all three of these:

```
proxy_cache_use_stale updating;
proxy_cache_background_update on;
proxy_cache_lock on;
```

There's an excellent explanation here in the nginx blog of why these three are needed and what they do: https://www.nginx.com/blog/nginx-caching-guide/.